# Producing lecture notes and handouts with spaces for students to fill in details

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to produce handouts for students of lecture notes that I've written using Beamer -- I'd like the handouts and presentation slides to look **exactly** the same except have gaps in the handout version for students to fill in information.  In other words, I'd like to preserve the spacing with say specific equations/text removed.

I've tried the ***\only*** command, but that doesn't seem to preserve the spacing (it removes it completely and closes up the gap).

Is there a simple way to do this without just setting the text to "white" or having to insert spacing commands everywhere? [I can do it this way, but would prefer something more "automatic"]

Comment: You can use `\visible<handout:0>{stuff to hide in handout}`.

Comment: @kevin Thanks -- this was driving me insane.  I just found out that I can do `\onslide<handout:0>` too, but `\invisible<handout>` seems cleaner.

Comment: Related, maybe duplicate?: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220723/enhanced-fill-in-the-blank-document, using a modified `censor` package.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I don't think this is a duplicate because, at least as stated, the requirements here are much simpler and can be met by `beamer`. `censor` seems unnecessary here. [It may be a duplicate of something else - I just don't see it as a duplicate of that particular question.]

Comment: @cfr A good point you make.

Answer (score 5):

This creates a command `\handoutgap{}` which will leave a gap in handout mode, typesetting the content normally otherwise.

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\newcommand\handoutgap[1]{\invisible<0| handout:1->{#1}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
    This is some text and \handoutgap{that bit is} missing.
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The handout:

[image: handout]

The presentation:

[image: presentation]

Comment: +1, a challenge also: could you make `\handoutgap` overlay aware `:P`

Comment: @KevinC In what sense? Overlays have no meaning for handouts, do they? That is, what should the overlay specification do?

Comment: @KevinC Note that it is trivial to make the command overlay aware because `beamer` alters the syntax of `\newcommand`. In a sense, it already is overlay aware but no use is made of any overlay specification in the macro. I just don't see what such a specification could usefully be used for.

Comment: Yes, it's easy to define overlay aware commands in Beamer, but not so much if you want to have the `<handout:1->` option as its default. I haven't thought of an easy way to do that, well, other than introducing conditional statements like `\if`.

Comment: For example, I have a `\fillblank` command defined as `\newcommand<>{\fillblank}[1]{\uline{$\quad$\visible#2{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}$\quad$}}`. In the `presentation` mode, `Question: \fillblank<+->{answer}` first shows the question with a blank, and then the answer appears in blue. Suppose in the `handout` mode I want to hide the answer, as the OP does, I would have to include `| handout:0` for every `\fillblank` I use. This is inconvenient.

Comment: So I'm wondering if one could "append" the option `handout:0` to `\fillblank`,  as `append style` in TikZ, so that whenever `handout` mode is switched on, it always hides the content, and in `presentation` mode, it obeys whatever overlay instructions that are given. BTW, I don't hide answers in my handouts; that's I'm putting off searching for a solution till this question comes up `:p`

Comment: @KevinC I think you should ask your own question with a full MWE. It isn't possible to deal with it properly in comments and it isn't appropriate to post a response as an answer to a different question. The need in this question was relatively simple and a simple solution is the best one. Doing stuff with TiKZ raises different issues.