# Create a box around a hidden text in a Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

I used the solution mentioned here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225079/75983 to hide parts of my presentations in the handout version of the slides. I am wondering **if it is possible to place a box around the empty space with a special sign** so that students can figure out there is a hidden text that need to be filled. *The space should be on the same size of the hidden text and take care if the text is in a single or multiple line.* 
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[16pt,notheorems,handout]{beamer}
\newcommand\handoutgap[1]{\invisible<0| handout:1->{#1}}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
%%%%
\title[MWE]{Test}
\author[Author]{Author}
\date{\today}


%------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
Single line equation
\handoutgap{
\[ x^2 + y^2 = z^2, \]
}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
System of equations
\handoutgap{
\begin{align*}
  x^2 + y^2 & = z^2 \\
  r^2 + t^2 & = m^2 \\
  s^2 + k^2 & = n^2
\end{align*}
}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `tcolorbox` for it. For the special sign you may want to have a look at the `overlay` option, but usually a frame should suffice to say "Fill it". Besides I consider it a good idea to give some more space (e.g. the line width) for students to fill something in. But you can set the width of the box using the `width` key.

[image: handout]

```
\documentclass[16pt,notheorems,handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newcommand\handoutgap[1]{\tcolorbox[arc=0pt,colback=white,size=fbox,colframe=black]\invisible<0| handout:1->{#1}\endtcolorbox}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
%%%%
\title[MWE]{Test}
\author[Author]{Author}
\date{\today}


%------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
Single line equation
\handoutgap{
\[ x^2 + y^2 = z^2, \]
}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
System of equations
\handoutgap{
\begin{align*}
  x^2 + y^2 & = z^2 \\
  r^2 + t^2 & = m^2 \\
  s^2 + k^2 & = n^2
\end{align*}
}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you TeXnician for your help. It is working fine now.